# Can we write ODBC query for saved searches formula in Netsuite. To get same output by running query?

Tags: odbc, cloud, netsuite, informatica, erp

We have serval saved searches in  Netsuite account and the client wants . Every saved searches formula should be written in ODBC query?
Would it possible to write ODBC query for 100 of formula in Netsuite?
Please help .

Answer (score 0):

You have to retrieve all the base data and perform the calculations for any formulas client side due to limitations in the NetSuite API. As mentioned well by CDATA (another provider of an ODBC connector for NetSuite):

> NetSuite imposes a few limitations on saved searches. Calcualted
>   columns (formulas) cannot be retrieved via the NetSuite API. Only
>   columns directly from the table may be retrieved. If you have a
>   calculation in your saved search, you would need to return each
>   individual column used in the calculation and perform the calculation
>   client side. Ie:
>
> `SELECT (col1 / col2) AS calc FROM MySavedSearch`
>
> Saved searches that
>   return an aggregation or summary (Group / Count / Sum / Minimum /
>   Maximum / Average) cannot be returned at all. The NetSuite API will
>   throw an exception upon attempting to retrieve these saved searches.
>   Due to this limitation, these saved searches are unavailable for our
>   and any other third party tool.

Ref: [CData ODBC Driver for NetSuite 2017: Saved Searches](http://cdn.cdata.com/help/DNC/odbc/pg_savedsearches.htm)

Comment: Thanks, @Brain this will really helps.